# Providing catalina.home value in wildfly server arguments

Tags: log4j, wildfly-10, catalina

I'm using log4j for logging in my project. In log4j.xml, I'm providing the path of the logfile to be generated with the help of variable catalina.home. You can find the snippet below:

```
  <appender name="MyAppender1" class="org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender">
     <param name="File" value="${catalina.home}/MyLog.log" />
     <param name="DatePattern" value="'.'yyyy-MM-dd" />
     <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
         <param name="ConversionPattern" value="[%p] %d %c %M - %m%n"/>          
     </layout>
  </appender>
```

I want to provide the value of catalina.home in the arguments inside standalone.conf.bat by using value of **JBOSS_LOG_DIR** variable, by using this command

```
set "JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% -Djboss.modules.system.pkgs=org.jboss.byteman -Dcatalina.home=%JBOSS_LOG_DIR%"
```

But all I'm getting is blank value in front of **catalina.home** as you can see in the log generated while starting the server.

```
-Dprogram.name=standalone.bat -Xms64M -Xmx512M -XX:MetaspaceSize=96M -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=256m -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Djboss.modules.system.pkgs=org.jboss.byteman -Dcatalina.home= -Dorg.jboss.boot.log.file=D:\Softwares\wildfly_2\standalone\log\server.log -Dlogging.configuration=file:D:\Softwares\wildfly_2\standalone\configuration/logging.properties
```

If I'm giving a static path here instead of JBOSS_LOG_DIR variable, it is working fine.

Also, I tried to set the same to **JBOSS_LOG_DIR**  in **standalone.sh** (which I commented), in the below code :

```
    while true; do
   if [ "x$LAUNCH_JBOSS_IN_BACKGROUND" = "x" ]; then
      # Execute the JVM in the foreground
      eval \"$JAVA\" -D\"[Standalone]\" $JAVA_OPTS \
        \"-Dcatalina.home="$JBOSS_LOG_DIR"\"\
         \"-Dorg.jboss.boot.log.file="$JBOSS_LOG_DIR"/server.log\" \
         \"-Dlogging.configuration=file:"$JBOSS_CONFIG_DIR"/logging.properties\" \
         #\"-Dcatalina.home="$JBOSS_LOG_DIR"\"\#
         -jar \""$JBOSS_HOME"/jboss-modules.jar\" \
         $MODULE_OPTS \
         -mp \""${JBOSS_MODULEPATH}"\" \
         org.jboss.as.standalone \
         -Djboss.home.dir=\""$JBOSS_HOME"\" \
         -Djboss.server.base.dir=\""$JBOSS_BASE_DIR"\" \
         "$SERVER_OPTS"
      JBOSS_STATUS=$?
   else
      # Execute the JVM in the background
      eval \"$JAVA\" -D\"[Standalone]\" $JAVA_OPTS \
        \"-Dcatalina.home="$JBOSS_LOG_DIR"\"\
         \"-Dorg.jboss.boot.log.file="$JBOSS_LOG_DIR"/server.log\" \
         \"-Dlogging.configuration=file:"$JBOSS_CONFIG_DIR"/logging.properties\" \
          #\"-Dcatalina.home="$JBOSS_LOG_DIR"\"\#
         -jar \""$JBOSS_HOME"/jboss-modules.jar\" \
         $MODULE_OPTS \
         -mp \""${JBOSS_MODULEPATH}"\" \
         org.jboss.as.standalone \
         -Djboss.home.dir=\""$JBOSS_HOME"\" \
         -Djboss.server.base.dir=\""$JBOSS_BASE_DIR"\" \
         "$SERVER_OPTS"
```

But in this case, **-Dcatalina.home** itself is not getting appened in the string. Can you kindly help me where is it going wrong ? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using `standalone.sh` you'd need to edit the `JAVA_OPTS` in the `standalone.conf`. Not that one that ends in `.bat` as that is for the `standalone.bat` script.

Another issue you'd have is the `JBOSS_LOG_DIR` is set after the `standalone.conf` is executed.

One option would be to use the `jboss.server.log.dir` property instead of `catalina.home` in your `log4j.xml` file. The other option would be to do something like `JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Dcatalina.home=$JBOSS_HOME/standalone/log`. However the previous option would be preferred.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer :). Really appreciate it.
I used jboss.server.log.dir in place of catalina.home and it works like a charm now.
Though for informative purpose only, can you suggest why catalina.home may not be working ? I remember earlier me and my friend used to work with jboss 7.2 and used catalina.home but it used to work properly. Is it deprecated now ?

Comment: From the example it would be a timing thing. For WildFly though JBoss Web (a Tomcat fork) is no longer the servlet container. It was replaced by Undertow so the old Tomcat like properties likely won't work.

Comment: Ok . Thanks again for the help. Really appreciate it !